# Typescript Error - TS2339 on ComponentRef

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing a typescript error

> error TS2339: Property 'close' does not exist on type '{}'

Code where i face issue  :-

**home.directive.ts**

```
    import { Directive, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core'; 
@Directive({
  selector: '[child]'
})
export class HomeDirective {
  constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }
  openComp(component:any) : ComponentRef<any> {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    let componentFactory =
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    let componentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
    componentRef.instance.close.subscribe(() => {
            //do something
            });

    return componentRef;
  }

}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import {  Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from '../home.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  providers: [HomeService],
  template: `<h3>child-component</h3>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  close = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.close.emit('closed');
  }
}
```

and i am invoking openComp()

**home.component.ts**

```
import {  Component ,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { HomeDirective } from './home.directive';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/index';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-home',
  providers: [HomeService],
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
  entryComponents: [ChildComponent],
})
export class HomeComponent {
  @ViewChild(HomeDirective) homeDirective: HomeDirective;
  constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {
  }
  openChild() {
    this.homeDirective.openComp(ChildComponent);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out? I am a newbie in angular 2 and typescript. my codings might be wrong. please correct me if my codings are wrong.

PS: Even though typescript throws this error, this code works as i wanted(in dev build). but cant do prod build

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
(<ChildComponent>componentRef.instance).close.subscribe
```

Or

```
(<any>componentRef.instance).close.subscribe
```